# Evaluating a limit involving a definite integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I want to prove the following limit evaluates to $0$ without using any techniques that involve complex numbers. I already solved it using residues and it's pretty straight forward, but it feels rather unpleasant using such a tool.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(nx)}{x^2+4}\,dx$$

I also tried differentiation under the integral sign, but I got to a point where things got too messy to be handled gracefully so I came here to ask for help.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you expand on this?

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riemann-Lebesgue lemma states

> If $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$, then
>   $$\lim_{p\to +\infty } \int\limits_a^bf(x)e^{ipx}\,dx=0.$$

Using Euler formula ($e^{i\varphi} = \cos\varphi + i\sin\varphi$) one can show that also

> $$\lim_{p\to +\infty } \int\limits_a^bf(x)\sin px\,dx=0 \quad\text{ and }\quad \lim_{p\to +\infty } \int\limits_a^bf(x)\cos px\,dx=0.$$

In your case $[a,b]$ is $[0,2\pi]$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+4}$.

Comment: Russian typo in the middle of the 2nd formula, you likely meant to write "and" instead :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $f(x)$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^bf(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$$Here, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+4}$ is continuous in $[0,2\pi]$ and so integrable.

Comment: err...how does stating the conclusion preceded by 'In general' make for an answer, let alone a proof ?

Comment: @fargg he probably assumed the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is generally known...